# Can't Remote in or log in to tfs SERVER

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, team-foundation-server, visual-studio-2010

1. Tried rebooting- It boots but never comes to the login screen stops at blank blue screen [note:not BSOD]
2. People can still use all the tfs services via[public ip] just fine but I can't ping it with local ip or remote in or directly log in

I really don't want to loose any data any help appreciated

Server 2008 Standard, Bios post screen seems ok and no error,

Comment: Anything change recently on the box, especially updates/drivers?  Can you try remote management tools to view the services that are started, eventvwr, etc?  I'd say reboot into Safe Mode and start checking the services, msconfig, and event logs, but you might be able to get something working remotely without doing that.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, remote viewing via mmc didn't work either but I will try t boot it in safe mode in off hours. As far as changes...windows updates..I will update this post as soon as i can do this. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved but the mystery still remains. This is very wired....As I mentioned above that I can see the bios post screen and then just blue blank screen. After hooking up a different monitor directly I can see the normal display.[Very wired because the original monitor is hooked to a kvm and i can view other servers just fine tried switching cables from other servers too and at the same time i can see the post screen??]. I am not sure how but the remote desktop connection did get disabled so I enabled it. Made backups and Image of the server.